# Take a full screenshot for all webview in swift

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Does anyone know how can I take a full screenshot for all my web view using code in swift ( not the screen ! because the webview is long and we must scroll to view the all content ) and share it via `UIActivityViewController`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following code after web view is loaded:

EDITED: run this code in simulator then check the screenshot.jpeg file in your documents app directory

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

let fileDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    var urlPath = "http://www.bbc.com/"
    let requestUrl = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestUrl!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    webView.delegate = self

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {


    if (!webView.loading){

        var webViewFrame = webView.frame

        webView.frame = CGRectMake(webViewFrame.origin.x, webViewFrame.origin.y, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.scrollView.contentSize, false, 0);
        self.webView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)
        var currentFileName = "screenshot.jpeg"
        var imageFilePath = fileDirectory[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)
        var imageFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
        imageData.writeToURL(imageFileURL!, atomically: false)
        webView.frame = webViewFrame
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I get an error in this : fileDirectory[0]
anw , I try your code like this:

var webViewFrame = webView.frame     
webView.frame = CGRectMake(webViewFrame.origin.x, webViewFrame.origin.y, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.scrollView.contentSize, false, 0);
self.webView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

webView.frame = webViewFrame

but the screen shot is not for all the webview :/ just like a screen shot

Comment: About the error use the following `var fileDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)` . About the screenshot are you sure that webview is fully loaded? Just tried it for different sites and its working fine

Comment: about the correction of the first : we need edit this now : var imageFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)    

about the second : yea I am usre , because the webview is local ( in my project I have the html file ) 

in my UIActivityViewController , I call the : image   ( UIImage ) , not another var

Comment: when I set in the place of: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height  this value:10000 , all the content is visible but the image created is too long ... I dont know what is the problem with contentSize.height ?! @zellb

Comment: I think I know what is the problem ! the image created content a white space on the top = the space missed in the bottom !! .  so how can I fix this problem ? @zellb

Comment: yes bro :/ why I have a white space on the top ?:S . because of the top bar ?

Comment: This code works fine if the view controller just contain a webview , but my view controller have a top bar with back button... , so the screen shot contain a white space on the top , but if I scroll down before taking the screen shot the white space disappeared .. how can I fix this problem plz ?
@zellb

Comment: @HassanTaleb just tried it with banner above the webview and its working in my iOS 8.1 simulator (no space at the top of the picture)

Comment: what banner? I don't understand :/ , can I send you an image to your email ? or contact you on fb?

Comment: Banner in my case is just a blank UIView with some colored background. If you can upload image somewhere do it and post the link here

Comment: this is the normal screen : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq2jaq5obezt1uf/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Jan%2022%2C%202015%2C%203.34.08%20PM.png?dl=0

this is the screen shot when i press share ...:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckqv7k41so8d9pz/Attachment-1.jpeg?dl=0

when I get back and croll the webview a black line appear in the bottom:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ubk35gwxh95ffx/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Jan%2022%2C%202015%2C%203.34.21%20PM.png?dl=0

@zellb

Comment: please download the last image because the background of dropbox is black

Comment: Can i have you html file as well ?

Comment: This image describe 100% the problem : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwq4a2dcsnxmqob/prob.png?dl=0    plz check it @zellb

Comment: NOTE: The result is not like a screen shot ! because when I choose another LONG html page , all the content appear except the bottom part of the page  ( with same dimensions of the image in the link )
NOTE: Dimensions of the white top bar = Dimensions of the bottom bar missed   @zellb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69446/discussion-between-zellb-and-hassan-taleb).

Comment: i am able to convert to image but only the visible portion is coming up, rest is shown as white. I even tried setting a higher value for webframe height @HassanTaleb but same result.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `WKWebView` in Swift 5

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        let configuration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
        configuration.rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: (self.webView.scrollView.contentSize))

        webView.takeSnapshot(with: configuration) {image, error in
            if let image = image {
                self.saveImage(imageName: "snapshot.jpg", image: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great! your code work!!! but there is a only problem: if you scroll down the webview, the snapshot is incorrect

Comment: i am getting blank image on iOS 13+ . Works fine on lower devices

Comment: Checked wtih XCode 11.5 and this answer no longer captures the whole page height.

Comment: Added the hack of accepted answer (resize the webview to the height of webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) works.

Comment: This works for me in iOS 13.3 but does't work in  13.4 and 12.4.3