# Take screenshot of whole WebView in swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, webview, swift4, snapshot

I really hope you can help me.
In my project I have a WebView opening a specific page and a button, what I need to do is taking a screenshot of the whole web page and export it as image or pdf when user press the button.

Here is what I have in my ViewCnotroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL (string: "https://www.google.com")
    QuizView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func ShotBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.WebView.image], applicationActivities: nil)

}
}
```

Now I know that value of type UIWebView has no member image, but the only example I found was using an UIImage insted WebView.

I saw this answer [Get UIWebView content and convert it to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644944/get-uiwebview-content-and-convert-it-to-image) but I was looking for something in swft 4

How can I do it?
Thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get UIWebView content and convert it to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644944/get-uiwebview-content-and-convert-it-to-image)

Comment: Hi, thenkyou for your suggestion, mybe I'm asking the same thing but how can I do that in swift? I'm a biginner

Comment: [is this is what you are looking?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986888/1066828), [also take a look at this](http://swiftgazelle.com/2015/08/how-to-take-uiwebview-screenshot-in-swift-on-ios/)

Comment: Yes I think the first one is ok, but I'm getting 2 errors:

1 QuizView.frame = CGRectMake(webViewFrame.origin.x, webViewFrame.origin.y, QuizView.scrollView.contentSize.width, QuizView.scrollView.contentSize.height) 

ERROR: ’CGRectMake' is unavailable in Swift 


2 var imageFilePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(currentFileName)

ERROR: Value of type '[String]' has no member 'appendingPathComponent'

Can you help me please…@Fahim Parker